# hashlib can't find ripemd160

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

When I try to use `ripemd160` with `hashlib` it says it can't find it.

I used `easy_install hashlib` which installed hashlib but it still can't find ripemd160.

I'm using Ubuntu and python2.7

```
def hexHash(str, withHash = None):
    h = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    h.update(str)
    if withHash != None:
        return h.hexdigest()[0:6]
    else:
        return '#'+h.hexdigest()[0:6]
```

> ValueError: unsupported hash type

Comment: Can you show the code you are using and the exact error message given?

Comment: Yeah I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashlib is part of Python's standard library, so you don't have to install it.

However, the only hash algorithms that are guaranteed to be available are  md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, and sha512.

Others *may* be available depending on the SSL library that is used on your platform.

You can run `openssl list-message-digest-algorithms` in a terminal to see which algorithms are available.

(**Note**: as of openssl 1.1.1, the above command doesn't work. Try `openssl dgst -list`)

The above assumes that Python uses the system's SSL library, which might not be the case.

Or (better) from Python:

```
import hashlib

print(hashlib.algorithms_available)
```

If `ripemd160` isn't available, you should probably look into re-installing your SSL library with different options. (Assuming Python uses the system's SSL)

If you are changing your SSL library to one with a different version number, you will have to rebuild anything that depends on it as well.

Comment: python 3.10 under termux shows ripemd160 available, but gives the above error when attempting `hashlib.new('ripemd160')`

Comment: hmm, openssl shows `rmd160` available, I wonder if it's the same and if the python module doesn't know of the name change.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx OpenSSL3 disabled ripemd160, it must be manually enabled now, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72508879/2922723

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx On FreeBSD 13, using OpenSSL 1.1.1 and Python 3.9 & 3.11, `hashlib.new('ripemd160')` works. Verify that your Python is actually linked against openssl.