# Unsupported hash type ripemd160 with hashlib in Python

Tags: python, hashlib, ripemd

After a thorough search, I have not found a complete explanation and solution to this very common problem on the entire web. All scripts that need to encode with hashlib give me error:

**Python 3.10**

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
```

return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/hashlib.py", line 166, in __hash_new
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/hashlib.py", line 123, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type ripemd160
```

I already tried to check if that hash exists in the library, and if I have it:

`print(hashlib.algorithms_available)`: {'md5', 'sm3', 'sha3_512', 'sha384', 'sha256', 'sha1', 'shake_128', 'sha224', 'sha512_224', 'sha512_256', 'blake2b', **'ripemd160'**, 'md5-sha1', 'sha512', 'sha3_256', 'shake_256', 'sha3_384', 'whirlpool', 'md4', 'blake2s', 'sha3_224'}

I am having this problem in a vps with linux, but in my pc I use Windows and I don't have this problem.

I sincerely appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Any others missing? Could you run [this](https://tio.run/##XYy9DsIwDIT3PIW3FgmxdEHdeQVW5CJDLJI4cs1Pnz4lQgGJm0733V1ezEsa9llL4ZhFDTzOPvDk3EUUEkYCTi3cYbiKsvk4n/CBHHAKNDp4y3T5mKpWT/Ts68XmS7Jysr6TW7eFH6HXmbLBEcOdDqqi4/@Aato2paw) and share your output?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hashlib uses OpenSSL for ripemd160 and apparently OpenSSL disabled some older crypto algos around version 3.0 in November 2021. All the functions are still there but require manual enabling. See [issue 16994 of OpenSSL github project](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/16994) for details.

To quickly enable it, find the directory that holds your OpenSSL config file or a symlink to it, by running the below command:

```
openssl version -d
```

You can now go to the directory and edit the config file (it may be necessary to use sudo):

```
nano openssl.cnf
```

Make sure that the config file contains following lines:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect

[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect

[default_sect]
activate = 1

[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

Tested on: OpenSSL 3.0.2, Python 3.10.4, Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS aarch64, I have no access to other platforms at the moment.

Comment: Well done. I had solved in this way an error in Zeronet.

Comment: its great. the release notes bold sections said 'Added RIPEMD160 to the default provider'  in nov'22 and in Dec'21 it says its moved and 'All of the low-level MD2, MD4, MD5, MDC2, RIPEMD160, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512 and Whirlpool digest functions have been deprecated.'  - clearly deprecated.